# DbLinq generic extension method - string as keyselector?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, exception, dblinq

The following snippet indicates what I want:

```
public static class DblinqExtension
{
    public static int MaxId<T>(this DbLinq.Data.Linq.Table<T> table) where T : class
    {
        var val = table.OrderByDescending(x => "Id").FirstOrDefault();
        return Convert.ToInt32(val);
    }
}
```

With DbMetal I've generated the mapping classes. Every table I have has the column Id (which is obviously an integer) and I want to know the MAX id.

Anyone any idea how I can get my snippet working??

**Thanks!**

---

I've found this article: [OrderBy with a String keySelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658138/orderby-with-a-string-keyselector)

With that suggestion applied my code will become:

```
public static int MaxId<T>(this DbLinq.Data.Linq.Table<T> table) where T : class
{
    var val = table.OrderByDescending(CreateSelectorExpression<T>("Id")).FirstOrDefault();
    return Convert.ToInt32(val);
}

private static Expression<Func<T, Int32>> CreateSelectorExpression<T>(string propertyName) where T : class
{
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    return (Expression<Func<T, Int32>>)Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, propertyName), 
        parameterExpression
    );
}
```

BUT now I get an error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've figured it out!!

```
    public static int MaxId<T>(this DbLinq.Data.Linq.Table<T> table) where T : class
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "ID");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(body, param);

        var val = table.OrderByDescending(lambda).FirstOrDefault();
        return Convert.ToInt32(val.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetGetMethod().Invoke(val, null));
    }
```

Thanks a lot @Yahia for your hint with the GetProperty part!

Answer (score 2):

not sure but try

```
var Result = from x in table select x.Max ( x => x.Id );
```

EDIT - if you need to take Id as string into the expression:

```
var Result = from x in table select x.Max ( x => x.GetType().GetProperty ("Id").GetGetMethod().Invoke (x, null) );
```

EDIT - if you need to split up:

```
var Result1 = from x in table select x; var Result2 = Result1.Max(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetGetMethod().Invoke(x, null));
```

EDIT - if "Id" is a field then you need this:

```
var Result1 = from x in table select x; 
var Result2 = Result1.Max(x => x.GetType().GetField ( "Id" ).GetValue(x));
```

Comment: Where does _x come from?? And table is a generic btw, of type class

Comment: I need to split up

            `var Result1 = from x in table select x;`
            `var Result2 = Result1.Max(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetGetMethod().Invoke(x, null));`
Now I get an **ArgumentException was unhandled** Parameter

Comment: see my edit - in the second statement you use Result where you need to use Result1

Comment: Yeah, typo on my side! If this was the error, the code did not compile. The code compiles and the error comes at run time!

Comment: not sure but in your code you write "ID" and in your original post you wrote "Id"... perhaps this is the reason ?

Comment: It's now ID because Id gave the same exception... So no difference at all using Id or ID

Comment: @Yahia let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1679/discussion-between-321x-and-yahia)